# How do I modify text in a basic .apk file

Tags: android, apk

I have a basic .apk file I want to modify, It displays the program is really basic all it does is ask a question with radio buttons and you need to select one and it will go to the next question

I want to change a question like

```
What is your favorite food ?
O Burgers
O Steak
O Pasta
O Cake
```

to say

```
What color is the sky ?
O Blue
O Red
O Green
O Pink
```

I've renamed the .apk on my PC from application.apk to application.apk.zip
and extracted it, but all I really find is .xml files that I can't edit and images.

Comment: Do you have the code for this project? You will need to make the change in the source code and then compile it into a new .apk file.

Comment: ...Or decompile it, make changes, and compile again.

Comment: I do not have the source code, that is the problem, not sure how to decompile and recompile is